# MySQL: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE adds extra character '\r'

Tags: mysql, webclient.uploaddata

I have a table like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE `tblinquiries` (
  `UID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReviewDate` date NOT NULL,
  `InquiryId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AuditStatus` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`InquiryId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have a csv file with data:

```
UID,ReviewDate,InquiryId,AuditStatus

UID1,2018-07-06,109814969,Check

UID2,2018-07-06,109866072,Check

UID3,2018-07-06,109911408,Check

UID4,2018-07-06,109798278,Check
```

I use below command to to upload the data:

```
   $location = '../uploads/';
   $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   $filePath = $location.$name;
   $table = 'tblinquiries';

   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$filePath.'"
   INTO TABLE '.$table.'
   FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
   LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
   IGNORE 1 LINES
```

It uploads the data but adds extra character "\r" from the second line. I exported the data and got like below:

```
('UID4', '2018-07-06', '109798278', 'Check'),
('UID1', '2018-07-06', '109814969', 'Check\r'),
('UID2', '2018-07-06', '109866072', 'Check\r'),
('UID3', '2018-07-06', '109911408', 'Check\r');
```

After running:

```
SELECT AuditStatus, LENGTH(AuditStatus) FROM `tblinquiries`
```

got:

```
AuditStatus LENGTH(AuditStatus)
Check          5
Check          6
Check          6
Check          6
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You might try changing the line terminated to \r\n with proper escaping of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sloan suggested I changed the line terminators and that solved the problem.
Here is the final code.

```
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$filePath.'"
        INTO TABLE '.$table.'
        FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'
        IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your source data has those `\r` control characters, because `LOAD DATA` doesn't typically add data to the source file (unless you tell it to do so, which does not appear to be the case).  We can try running `RTRIM` on the `AuditStatus` column:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$filePath.'"
INTO TABLE '.$table.'
FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(UID, ReviewDate, InquiryId, @AuditStatus)
SET AuditStatus = RTRIM(@AuditStatus);
```